# Flood light pole components

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, electrical, lighting

I saw this flood light pole. It has two LED bulbs, but I do not know what the box in the middle is (it was not an LED), could you guys help me understand what this could be? This flood light is located in a plaza parking lot called Churchill square, in St John's, NL, Canada.

[image]

Comment: I do not have one at the moment but I will try to go take a better one and update the post. Any ideas of what it could be tho?

Comment: Please mention the location where this photo was taken. I would have guessed IR LED or Wi-Fi antenna.

Comment: Hey! I just updated the question to include location, and I will try to get a better picture of the box later today.

Comment: just a guess, could it be a power converter? LED modules might want a lower voltage than the 480V that the previous generation of big streetlights used? though I think the current generation are also built to accept it

Comment: How do you know they are not metal halide lights which would need a ballast/transformer the size of the box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1VSkhz8y-hY

In here you can see, at 17th second, that these poles are located at the corners of the parking lot of the shopping center. And they are not present elsewhere in the city.

It is not a camera, those needs round casing.

It is not a network tower, they are too close and those are looking like vertical box and dont like other boxes nearby. But lower frequencies can work fine with LEDs nearby.

It is not a PV, its a rather bulky box.

It is not a LED as you say.

I dont think it is a power supppy unit, as those are cheaper to service at a lower height.

My guess is that it is some sort of digital fence system for the shopping center that operates at a much lower frequency than a phone.

Probably to track trolleys as they are moved away and to lock their wheel to prevent people taking these trolleys elsewhere.

Tower height is excessive, and light lamps are added at a lower height. Meaning these towers need their height for something else. Digital fence benefits from such a height, as it doesnt get obstructed by vehicles, and provides more even power of a sigal within its zone.